# How to call function within same module

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
export default (function () {
  (...)
  return {
    open: () => {
      (...)
    },
    close: () => {
      (...)
    },
    get: () => {
      (...)
    }
  }
})();
```

I wanna call the `close()` in `get()` function like this :

```
get: () => {
   close();
}
```

I tried to use `this` but it doesn't work.

Please give me some advice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it has something to do with arrow functions bind this, try puting var self=this; and then call self.close(), put self outside of functions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either use *method* properties instead (for which `this` rules will work just like with standard non-arrow functions):

```
export default (function () {
  (...)
  return {
    open() {
      (...)
    },
    close(){
      (...)
    },
    get() {
      (...)
      this.close();
    }
  }
})();
```

Or define all functions that you want to be able to cross-reference *before* the `return` statement:

```
export default (function () {
  (...)

  const close = () => {
    (...)
  };
  return {
    open: () => {
      (...)
    },
    close,
    get: () => {
      (...)
      close();
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I solve it using the first solution.